# String not parsing correctly with a space

Tags: java

I am a very new to Java, so my knowledge is very limited. I have been trying to find the problem in this block of code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class avgFinder {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Input numbers to average. Separate by a space.");
     String nums = scan.next();
     String[] parseNums = nums.split("[ ]");
     double sum = 0;
     int cnt = 0;
     for (int a=0; a<=parseNums.length-1; a++) {
       sum += Double.parseDouble(parseNums[a]);
       cnt++;
     }
     double mean = sum/cnt;
     System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
   }
}
```

But when I input a a set of numbers, only the first number gets printed instead of the actual mean. Example:

```
Input numbers to average. Separate by a space.
1 2 3
Mean: 1.0
```

Another thing is if I replace `nums.split("[ ]")` with `nums.split("[,]")` and put commas instead of spaces between the numbers in the output, it actually outputs the mean. I like spaces better though, it looks cleaner. Why is this happening?

Comment: `scan.next` will return only the next element in a line` use `scan.nextLine`

Comment: Why not just do ``nums.split(" ")``?

Comment: Yea I forgot about that, `scan.next` only scans up to the next space. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`

> nextLine returns complete line of text while next returns only one word

Also use `nums.split(" ");`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class avgFinder {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Input numbers to average. Separate by a space.");
     String nums = scan.nextLine();
     String[] parseNums = nums.split(" ");
     double sum = 0;
     int cnt = 0;
     for (int a=0; a<=parseNums.length-1; a++) {
       sum += Double.parseDouble(parseNums[a]);
       cnt++;
     }
     double mean = sum/cnt;
     System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. Code is fixed now. Also, why should I use `nums.split(" ")` instead of `nums.split("[ ]")`? Is it because of efficiency?

Comment: I don't know about nums.split("[ ]"). I usually follow nums.split(" ") for space splitting .

Comment: @asingh `nums.split("[ ]")` the parameter here is basicaly a regular expresion usualy in regular expresions `[ ]` means OR the values within the `[]` so something like `nums.split("[abc]")` will be splitted at a OR b OR c which in this case is useless.

Comment: @asingh Accept this answer freely if it solve your problem.

Comment: @asingh By the way your code can fail with `NumberFormatException` in case of non decimal input. like if some one enters a character instead of a number you should make a habit to check the input before processing it. Trust me it will save you a whole lot of trouble later.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Scanner.next()` will return the next element in a line before a space, so you only getting the first number in your input. Use `Scanner.nextLine()` which will return all the values on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.next() returns the next word. By default, words are separated by whitespace. So when you call Scanner.next(), your scanner reads the digits of the first number, hits a space, and says "ok, that's the end of the word. Time to return the result" and you end up with just the first number.

That's why it works when you replace the spaces with commas: Without any spaces, the scanner doesn't find whitespace until it reaches the line break, so it returns the whole line.

Scanner.nextLine() returns the entire line instead of just one word (it reads until it hits a line break), so I'd suggest using that instead.